# Making table using for-loop

Tags: javascript

I have this code. It's very good and has no error in it. But I don't like repeat the code `html += "td";` a lot. Eaven `html += "/td";`. It is seing not clearly code.
How can I code it in shorter code using for loop?

```
html = "<table>";
html += "<tr>";
for(var name in newArticle[1]){
  html += "<th>";
  html += name;
  html += "</th>";
}
html += "</tr>";
for (var i=0; i<newArticle.length; i++) {
    html += "<tr>";
    html += "<td>";
    html += newArticle[i]["id"];
    html += "</td>";
    html += "<td>";
    html += newArticle[i]["Forename"];
    html += "</td>";
    html += "<td>";
    html += newArticle[i]["Surname"];
    html += "</td>";
    html += "<td>";
    html += newArticle[i]["Age"];
    html += "</td>";
    html += "<td>";
    html += newArticle[i]["City"];
    html += "</td>";
    html += "<td>";
    html += newArticle[i]["ZIP"];
    html += "</td>";
    html += "</tr>";
}
html += "</table>";
  console.log(html);

  for(var name in newArticle[1]){
    console.log(name);
  }
```

You can note that `newArticle()` is an array and the table data is from array's elements.

Comment: No, it's not very good. `newArticle()` is not an array, it's a function call. But there's no function like that, it's undefined, which would make this whole thing to have at least one error. Your indentation is off, you don't properly declare variables and it's just bad, bad, bad. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: Don't manually create HTML like that. Look up the `createElement` and similar functions. Create element objects and append children to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newArticle = 
html = "<table>";
html += "<tr>";
for(var name in newArticle[1]){
  html += "<th>";
  html += name;
  html += "</th>";
}
html += "</tr>";
for (var i=0; i<newArticle.length; i++) {
  html += "<tr>";
  for(var key in newArticle[i])
  {
    html += "<td>";
    html += newArticle[i][key];
    html += "</td>";
  }
  html += "</tr>";
}
html += "</table>";
console.log(html);    
for(var name in newArticle[1]){
  console.log(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a new array (say myarr with elements in order as required by the column of the newArticle array.
Now to use the newArticle array in for loop like this -

```
newArticle[i][myarr[j]] ;
```

You can initiate j from 0 and keep incrementing it to get the next respective values .
Hope it helps .